# How Hide data before searching and display when searching with Anguler.js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

**So, I have this table that displays users taken from a server in angularjs. Here is the users object:

:**

```js
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('namesCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.names = [
        'Jani',
        'Carl',
        'Margareth',
        'Hege',
        'Joe',
        'Gustav',
        'Birgit',
        'Mary',
        'Kai'
    ];
});
```

**Here html :**

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="namesCtrl">


<p><input type="text" ng-model="test"></p>

<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="x in names | filter:test">
    {{ x }}
  </li>
</ul>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can hide list until user enters something in input like

```
<ul ng-if="test">
...
</ul>
```

Comment: Ok, but if it is a table, what should I do?

Comment: How this is different from table. Am I missing something here? Could you please elaborate your exact issue?